# Next.js 13 eCommerce dynamic routing

Tags: next.js, next.js13

My current eCommerce have dynamic routes. the urls have the folling schema:

Product List Page

```
/en-us/categoryLevel1
/en-ca/categoryLevel1
/en-uk/categoryLevel1/categoryLevel2
```

Product Details Page

```
/en-us/categoryLevel1/abc-1234567788
/en-ca/categoryLevel1/abcdesf-121122113
/fr-fr/categoryLevel1/abcabc-1111111
```

The categories name is dynamic.

How can I structure my Next.js project to match all urls?

Answer (score 0):

In your `pages` folder you can create this structure:

```
pages/
  [lang]/
    [category]/
      index.jsx
      [sub]/
       [product]/
        index.jsx
```

Then in the respectives files (index.jsx) you can take the variable with `useRouter` [next/router](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/router):

```
import { useRouter } from 'next/router'
export default function index(){
  const router = useRouter()
  const {id} = router.query //this is [lang], [category] and [sub]
  ...code
}
```

can see more here: https://nextjs.org/docs/routing/dynamic-routes

**Edit:**
To retrieve Product data in the `index.jsx` you just get the id of product passed by URL (for example: `/en-us/categoryLevel1/abc-12345678`) and then load it:

```
import { useRouter } from 'next/router'
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react'

export default function Index(){
  const router = useRouter()
  const {id} = router.query //this is [lang], [category] and [sub]
  const [product, setProduct] = useState(null)

  const loadProduct = async function (id) {
    // for exemple...
    const res = await fetch(`/api/product/${id}`, {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(data),
    })
    const response = await res.json()
    setProduct(response)
  
    return response
  }
  
  useEffect(() => {
    loadProduct(id)
  }, [id])

  return (
    <div>
      {/* HTML */}
      {product && product.name}
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: categoryLevel1 name is dynamic and how to get the product code and if I am inside a product list page or a product details page?

Comment: To make a product list and retrieve the product details you will need an API or statics JSON with respectives data.

Comment: Did you get it?

Comment: we decided to change the logic of the route and use static segments to avoid complexity